How to iterate over the RGB wheel?
I can't find a library that implements some sort of RGB iterator that iterates from red (255-0-0) to yellow (255-255-0) to etc. Is it possible to implement it?
Its struct should implement Iterator<Item=(u8,u8,u8)> and perhaps, it contains max_iters to change its length.
Searching for functions/methods in libraries, I have not found any implementation of it

I think it would be fairly trivial to iterate over HSV (or similar color space); just increment the hue value and use a hsv_to_rgb function to map to the RGB color space.

(255-0-0), (f64,f64,f64) - normally, f64 is from 0.0 to 1.0. Only uint8_t based colors are from 0 to 255.

oops, I meant (u8, u8, u8)

Those RGB components are separable cyclic triangle waves with different offsets clamped between 0 and 255. A little arithmetic gives us a relatively compact formula: use modulo to get cycles, absolute value gives us triangle wave, .min() and .max() clamps the value.
struct Rainbow(isize);

impl Rainbow {
    fn eval(&self, offset: isize) -> u8 {
        let x = 255 * 2 - ((self.0 + offset * 255) % (255 * 6) - 255 * 3).abs();
        x.min(255).max(0) as u8
    }
}

impl Iterator for Rainbow {
    type Item = (u8, u8, u8);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let rgb = (self.eval(3), self.eval(1), self.eval(5));
        self.0 += 1;
        Some(rgb)
    }
}

fn main() {
    for (r, g, b) in Rainbow(0).take(1024) {
        println!("({r}, {g}, {b})");
    }
}

Playground

I accept this as answer since i mistyped (u8, u8, u8) as (f64, f64, f64) but I would've accepted kmdreko's answer had I actually meant (f64, f64, f64)

I have made an implementation:
pub struct RainbowIterator {
    max: usize,
    current: usize,
}

impl RainbowIterator {
    pub fn new(max: usize) -> Self {
        Self { max, current: 0 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for RainbowIterator {
    type Item = (u8, u8, u8);
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut ret = (255, 255, 255);
        if self.current >= self.max {
            return None;
        }
        let progress: f64 = self.current as f64 / self.max as f64;
        let subprogress = progress % (1.0 / 6.0);
        let phase = (progress * 6.0) as u8;
        if phase == 0 {
            ret.2 *= 0;
            ret.1 = (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        } else if phase == 1 {
            ret.2 *= 0;
            ret.0 = 255 - (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        } else if phase == 2 {
            ret.0 *= 0;
            ret.2 = (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        } else if phase == 3 {
            ret.0 *= 0;
            ret.1 = 255 - (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        } else if phase == 4 {
            ret.1 *= 0;
            ret.0 = (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        } else {
            ret.1 *= 0;
            ret.2 = 255 - (255.0 * progress) as u8;
        }
        self.current += 1;
        return Some(ret);
    }
}


You could use a match instead of if else...

An idea is to simply increment a "hue" value and use a function to map HSV (or similar color space) to RGB. Conversion function adapted from here. You could then implement the iterator like so:
fn hsv_to_rgb(h: f64, s: f64, v: f64) -> (f64, f64, f64) {
    let i = (h * 6.0).floor();
    let f = h * 6.0 - i;
    let p = v * (1.0 - s);
    let q = v * (1.0 - f * s);
    let t = v * (1.0 - (1.0 - f) * s);

    match (i as u32) % 6 {
        0 => (v, t, p),
        1 => (q, v, p),
        2 => (p, v, t),
        3 => (p, q, v),
        4 => (t, p, v),
        _ => (v, p, q),
    }
}

fn rainbow_wheel(steps: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (f64, f64, f64)> {
    (0..steps).map(move |i| hsv_to_rgb(i as f64 / (steps - 1) as f64, 1.0, 1.0))
}

